# How do you run "cd" and then "ls" in "subprocess.run()"?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am attempting to create a basic terminal emulator.

Currently my code takes input, and pastes it straight into Subprocess.run.

```
import subprocess
while True:
    command = input("Input:")
    result = subprocess.run(
              command.split(),
              capture_output=True,
              encoding="utf-8")
    
    result.check_returncode()
    result = result.stdout
    print(result)
```

I would like to be able to run a series of commands in the same prompt.

For example, I would like to input

```
cd /Desktop
ls
```

and then

```
cat myfile.txt
```

However, "cd" returns an error:

```
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd'
```

Presumably, this is because subprocess.run creates a new subprocess for each command, so there is no point in such a command being supported.

Similarly, the problem rearises when inputting a command that requires sudo, eg

```
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/sda1
```

I am therefore wondering how subprocess (or a different library) can be used to run a series of processes in the same terminal in series, simply pasting plain text into a terminal and recieving the output back as plain text, with the ability to send commands to the same subprocess, rather then a new spawned subprocess.

(I am aware that such a utility creates a severe security issue, as it gives a program full access to the terminal)

Comment: You are trying to write a shell not Terminal Emulator, right? Shell takes these commands as input; TE is something that takes care of the basic editing, sending data to shell, displaying etc. Also, `cd` changes the current director of the program, it is not an executable like others.

Comment: `cd` is not an executable, it's a built-in command of the shell

Comment: Before you get any ideas, using `shell=True` will make the command "work". Except the newly changed directory will expire with the process it ran in (the subprocess shell), and it's therefore thoroughly useless. Use `os.chdir`.